# JS: does using && condition instead of if have optimization influence

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Saying, instead of `if (condition) { do something }` I use `condition && do something`. Does it have improvement in optimization?

Comment: Are you sure you're optimizing in the right spot? I mean, does that condition get executed so often that it's really worth your time trying to shave anything from it?

Comment: Only in that (very) slightly fewer characters will be sent over the wire (compressed), which a minifier will do for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Moreover, if the code needs optimizing, any modern JavaScript engine will do the necessary optimizing for you.

Write clear code. Optimize if and when there's a problem the engine doesn't fix for you.